# Problema para cargar Store Procedure con ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, stored-procedure, ado.net

estoy desarrollando una aplicación web ASP MCV con C#, para enlazar mi aplicación a una base de datos SQL Server 2012 he utilizado ADO.NET y he creado un Modelo.edmx como se aprecia en la imagen:
[image: Diagrama .edmx con las entidades]

El problema que se me presenta es que no veo todos los Procedimientos Almacenados que tengo en la base de datos, solo algunos, no los veo ni al momento de crear el edmx ni al momento de actualizarlo, pero verifico en la base de datos y si estan todos los Procedimientos. Solo puedo ver los Procedimientos que hice para Consultar, pero no los de Crear, Modificar y Eliminar.

Comment: Los seleccionaste cuando "jalabas" el modelo de datos desde la base de datos?

Comment: La verdad puede ser que no lo haya hecho, quizás se me pasó, pero al hacerle click derecho al diagrama sale la opción de "Update Model from Database" pero en el listado de los SP disponibles no salen los que mencioné. Sabes si borrar el edmx y volverlo a hacer resuelva el problema? Pero temo que se dañe el proyecto.

Comment: @AlbertoAtencio ¿ya seleccionó el edmx y seleccionó la opción `Run Custom Tool`?

Comment: No lo había hecho, acabo de hacerlo pero no ejecuta nada, no tiene efecto.

Comment: Si va a borrar el modelo de ADO.NET, asegurese de borrar el ConnectionString por igual y renombrar las cosas tal como las tenía en primer lugar, luego de eso solo puedo recomendar ver si es cuestión de permisos _(Cosa que dudo, porque creo que no puedes crear un SP visible para un usuario y para otros no)_.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, ya vi el problema, solo los SP que retornan valores (los de consulta) son vivibles en el ADO. Los SP que no veo si los puedo utilizar pero no se despliegan en el edmx.